# Filled \fatbslash?

Tags: fonts

I use the stmaryrd package to obtain $\fatbslash$. What is an efficient, and stable, way to fill the empty space inside the symbol so that it is uniformly black?

Comment: you can't really do it from tex, it would be simpler to just draw a similar shape in tikz or similar or to modify the font. It is in theory possibl eto extract the character outline from the font with pstricks and fill it but I wouldn't call that particularly efficient or stable you may as well just draw a fixed filled outline.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would that I were able to follow the simpler advice! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angles are not as round as in `\fatbslash`, but the dimensions are pretty much the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{l3draw}
\usepackage{color}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\filledbslash}{}
 {
  \mathbin
   {
    \mspace{1mu}
    \mathpalette \sapiens_filledbslash:nn \scan_stop:
    \mspace{1mu}
   }
 }

\box_new:N \l_sapiens_filledbslash_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sapiens_filledbslash:nn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \use:c {m@th} $#1\mkern-1mu\fatbslash\mkern-1mu$ }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box + \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpb_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_sapiens_filledbslash_box
   {
    \draw_begin:
    \draw_join_round:
    \draw_path_moveto:n { 0pt , \l_tmpa_dim }
    \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.43\l_tmpb_dim , \l_tmpa_dim }
    \draw_path_lineto:n { \l_tmpb_dim, 0pt }
    \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.57\l_tmpb_dim, 0pt }
    \draw_path_close:
    \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
    \draw_end:
   }
  \box_move_down:nn { \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box } { \box_use:N \l_sapiens_filledbslash_box }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

$a\fatbslash b$

$a\filledbslash b$

\fboxsep=-0.1pt \fboxrule=0.1pt

\fbox{$\mkern-1mu\fatbslash\mkern-1mu$}

\fbox{$\fatbslash$}

\fbox{$\filledbslash$}

{\ooalign{\color{red}$\fatbslash$\cr$\filledbslash$\cr}}

{\ooalign{$\filledbslash$\cr\color{red}$\fatbslash$\cr}}

{\ooalign{$\scriptstyle\filledbslash$\cr\color{red}$\scriptstyle\fatbslash$\cr}}

{\ooalign{$\scriptscriptstyle\filledbslash$\cr\color{red}$\scriptscriptstyle\fatbslash$\cr}}

\end{document}
```

[image]